# Form button navigation

Tags: asp.net

Is there a good reason why I can't do this

`<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Btn1" OnClick='<%# Response.Redirect("wibble.aspx?ID=" + Eval("ID")) %>'/>`

I get a compilation error: 
`The best overloaded method match for 'System.Convert.ToString(object, System.IFormatProvider)' has some invalid arguments`

I appreciate I can create a code behind routine to handle the redirect but I would like to be able to create these type of buttons on the fly.

I can use a `<asp:HyperLink>` and it works fine using the `NavigateUrl` property, but why can't I do this with a button?

Comment: Because `OnClick` is expecting the `Event` to execute not the code.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `OnClientClick` attribute instead. This will allow you to add Javascript code for the `onclick` HTML attribute.

```
<asp:Button runat="server" ID="Btn1" OnClientClick="window.location ='wibble.aspx?ID=<%# Eval("ID")).ToString() %>"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not do this as this will be rendered as input[type=submit] as html in browser, and for html its not functionality to redirect when you click on button.

If you have such request of having hyperlink in button , ASP.net gives linkbutton control , which will solve your need.

```
<asp:linkbutton PostBackUrl="~/something.aspx?id=1" runat="server">LinkButton</asp:linkbutton>
```